# How check value on select change in alpinejs?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am using Laravel with alpinejs and i have code like below

```
<div x-data="stest">
  <select x-model="selectedOption" @change="handleChange()">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="option1">Op 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Op 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and script

```
<script>
  function mkwd() {
    return {
      selectedOption: '',
      handleChange() {
        console.log('Selected:', this.selectedOption);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

And cant see any log on console. But when i add

```
<input type="text" @change="handleChange">
```

i see null in console co i am sure alpine works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The *x-data* function that returns the object must be the same defined in the script section:

```html
<div x-data="mkwd">
....
</div>

<script>
  function mkwd() {
    return {
        ....
```

If you are using AlpineJs V3 consider also [Alpine.data](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) to initialize your object